# I’m trying to code a blackjack game, can anyone help me with my score-checking solution? Python

Tags: python, if-statement

this is my code. As you can see by my comment at the top of my code, I want any value under 21 to return the value 0, exactly 21 to return a 1, and anything over 21 to return a 2. This is my best attempt, and almost everything works.

Except when I win in my blackjack game and get 21 points, where the output of winCheck() is still 0. Anything over 21 returns the value 2 correctly, just like when I’m still under 21 points I get returned a 0. I just can’t get it to return the value 1 when I hit 21 points.

Is there something I’ve misunderstood about if/elif statements?

```
# 0 = under 21, 1 = exactly 21, 2 = bust
def winCheck(points):
    if points <= 21:
        return 0
    elif points == 21:
        return 1
    elif points >= 21:
        return 2
```

Comment: the `>=` and `<=` sign checks for equality as well so it will work for 21

Comment: Is `21 <= 21`? [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: `<=` means "less than or equal".  21 is (obviously) equal to 21, so `21 <= 21` is true.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions are checked in order: if `points <= 21` is true (and it is if `points` is 21), your `if` statement never bothers checking `points == 21`. Simply altering the order of the checks will suffice:

```
def winCheck(points):
    if points == 21:
        return 0
    elif points <= 21:
        return 1
    elif points >= 21:
        return 2
```

Note, though, that if `points == 21` is false, then `points <= 21` and `points < 21` are equivalent. Using `<` (and `>`) is both more readable and allows you to peform the checks in any order, because only one of the three *can* be true for a given value of `points`.

```
def winCheck(points):
    if points == 21:
        return 0
    elif points < 21:
        return 1
    elif points > 21:
        return 2
```

or

```
def winCheck(points):
    if points < 21:
        return 0
    elif points == 21:
        return 1
    elif points > 21:
        return 2
```